# Place a letter randomly into an array in C++

Tags: c++, srand

I am creating a battleship game in C++ and I am having trouble figuring out how to randomly place 1x3 ships horizontally on my board. I took a 10x10 board filled with 'O' (for "ocean") and I am trying to just figure out how to randomly place even just a 1x1 'S' (for ship).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int rows=10;
    const int cols=10;
    srand(time(NULL));

    char board[100];

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("board.txt");
    for (int i=0; i<rows*cols; i++) fin >> board[i];
    fin.close();

    for (int r=0;r<rows;r++) {
        for (int c=0;c<cols;c++) {
            cout << board[r*rows+c] << " ";
       }
       cout << endl;
     }
}
```

My "board.txt" is the file that holds the 10x10 board. I am specifically looking for how to place just 1 letter 'S' randomly on the board so I can then figure out for myself how to place 'S S S' somewhere into the array horizontally.

Please keep in mind, I am taking a college course in C++ so I am still pretty new at this so no hate.

Answer (score 0):

Since your matrix is 10 x 10, to place an `S` somewhere you just need to generate a random number between 0 and 99 and use it as the index.

You can use [`uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) and e.g. an LCG<sup>1</sup> [`minstd_rand`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) for that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int rows = 10;
    const int cols = 10;
    uniform_int_distribution<int> dist(0, rows * cols - 1);
    random_device rnd_seed;
    minstd_rand rnd_gen { rnd_seed() };

    char board[100]{};

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("board.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows*cols; i++) fin >> board[i];
    fin.close();

    board[dist(rnd_gen)] = 'S'; // place S at a random location

    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            cout << board[r*rows + c] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> An [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) is very fast but can be predictable. For a game you might want to look into a [PRNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) like `mt19937` (slower but less predictable), or a true RNG, `random_device` (slowest).

Also see [this explanation](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful) of why `srand`/`rand()` is considered harmful.